# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2x}}{\cosh \left ( \pi x \right )}dx$ using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, laurent-series

The contour for the complex integral is the rectangle with vertices at $\left ( R,0 \right ), \left ( R,1 \right ),\left ( -R,1 \right ), \left ( -R,0 \right )$
The closed contour integral is equal to two pi times the residue at $z=\frac{i}{2}$. I am having major trouble expanding this in its Laurent series. Maybe the integral gurus here can provide answers.

Comment: Let $t=e^x.~$ This will yield an expression of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{t^{k-1}}{1+t^n}~dt.~$ Now let $u=\dfrac1{1+t^n}~,~$ and recognize the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral. Then all that's left to do is applying [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) to simplify the result. $($ A proof can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/714668/1) $).$ You'll get $\dfrac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\dfrac\pi n\bigg).$

Comment: @Lucian Nice, indeed!